# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Issue - "The field or property 'GUID' does not exist"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am having an issue with a SharePoint 2013 Workflow on SharePoint Designer. I can publish the workflow to the site with no problem. Once the workflow is in the started stage, it always gets suspended at the same spot. I get the error message: "The property 'GUID' does not exist."

This error occurs when I create a list item. For the output clause the only variable type it will let me select is GUID. If I change the variable to a string or integer, it says there is an error.

Here is where I can only let the variable "create2" be a GUID:
[image]

Here is the actual error from the site:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.